# Problem in Handling the Mouse click of CListCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a listctrl with CheckBox in it(LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES) .It is a single column List Control . My Problem is when I Click on the CheckBox the particular item is getting selected/UnSelected. But when I click on the Item text the corresponding Checkbox is not getting Selected/UnSelected . How to handle both the Scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check the item when the user clicks on the item text, you'll have to handle the NM_CLICK message, which is sent whenever the user clicks on the item.

Something along the lines of:

```
CYourListCtrl::OnNMClick(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{

LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);

int nItemIndex = pNMItemActivate->iItem;

BOOL bCurrentCheckState = GetCheck(nItemIndex);

SetCheck(nItemIndex, !bCurrentCheckState);

*pResult = 0;

}
```

I'm writing this without testing though, so you'll have to make sure that it doesn't conflict with the handler for clicks on the check box iteself.